# deshacer cambios en poligono de google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tengo un problema al momento de querer cambiar de posición un punto de un polígono cuando lo dibujo en google maps, al momento de dibujarlo valido que el lugar donde se posiciono no sea dentro de otro polígono, pero no logro que cuando mueva el mismo punto, este regrese al estado anterior.

Se que existe la función ya que al momento de mover el punto, sale un botón que realiza dicha acción.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se si exista la forma de llamarlo desde JavaScript, he visto la documentación, pero solo puedo atrapar el evento mas no usarlo de forma independiente

```
punto.addListener('remove_at', e=>{ 
   console.log(`remove_at: ${e}`); 
});
```

yo lo quiero usar en estos eventos que proporciona Google maps.

```
const puntos = this.polygon.getPaths() //se obtienen los puntos del polígono
let punto = puntos.getAt(0);
punto.addListener('insert_at', e=>{ 
    console.log(`insert_at: ${e}`); // aquí obtengo que punto estoy editando
    console.log(`latitud: ${this.polygon.getPath().getAt(e).lat()}, longitud: ${this.polygon.getPath().getAt(e).lng()}`)
});

punto.addListener('set_at', e=>{  
    console.log(`insert_at: ${e}`); // aquí obtengo que punto estoy editando
    console.log(`latitud: ${this.polygon.getPath().getAt(e).lat()}, longitud: ${this.polygon.getPath().getAt(e).lng()}`);
});
```

Así que cuando detecte que esta dentro de otro polígono, este regrese a su estado anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude hacerlo, no de la forma en la que yo quería pero funciono, ya que los eventos de `insert_at` e `set_at` me devuelve el índex del arreglo donde se encuentra, busque y encontré la función `removeAt(e)` el cual recibe el índex del punto que se realizo la acción.

El único error que tuve, es que al realizar la acción al momento, el polígono no se ha terminado de dibujar y por ende produce un error de que no se encuentra la propiedad, así que por eso le agregue un setTimeout, ya cuando se mueva o seleccione un punto del polígono, dejo que termine de dibujarlo y después lo valido.

Mi código quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
inicio_poligono: function(maps, editable, opacity, color, callback){
    try{
        if (color == undefined){
            color = "#fffff";
        }

        if (opacity == undefined){
            opacity = 0.8;
        }

        this.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeOpacity: opacity,
            editable: editable,
            map: maps
        });
        const puntos = this.polygon.getPaths() //se obtienen los puntos del poligono
        let punto = puntos.getAt(0);

        punto.addListener('insert_at', e=>{ 
            if (this.$parent.$parent.pointValidate(e)){
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.polygon.getPath().removeAt(e);
                }, 100);
            }
        });

        // punto.addListener('remove_at', e=>{ 
        //     console.log(`remove_at: ${e}`);
        // });

        punto.addListener('set_at', e=>{  
            if (this.$parent.$parent.pointValidate(e)){
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.polygon.getPath().removeAt(e);
                }, 100);   
            }
        });

        maps.addListener("click", event => {
            this.polygon.getPath().push(event.latLng);
        });
    }catch(Exception){
        console.error(Exception);
    }
}
```